# ESP8266 pHAT from Pimoroni does not working. `minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0` returns nothing

Tags: pi-3, esp8266

I bought myself this, https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/esp8266-phat.

I started with looking through this blog post, http://richardhayler.blogspot.nl/2016/02/getting-started-with-esp8266-iot-phat.html. At point number 5.

> 5. We need to stop the Pi using the Serial port for console messages. Edit /boot/cmdline.txt to remove 'console=ttyAMA0' from the line. You should be left with:
>
> `dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0  console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait`

Instead of `console=ttyAMA0` I have this `console=serial0,115200`. Then, I tried with **AND** without `console=serial0,115200` in my `/boot/cmdline.txt`. I am pretty sure the serial connection is disabled as well.

As the tutorial says, I tried to run my ESP8266 pHat with `minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0`. But it does not working (after I pressed enter there is a delay and then the program closes). Since I do not have `/dev/ttyAMA0` I tried with `/dev/serial0` still does not working.

I tried to run installation from `curl -sS get.pimoroni.com/iotphat | bash` as well but same thing happened.

I am using latest Raspbian Jessie and Raspberry PI 3 Model B

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/5538

Comment: That might be related, but I am not sure what should I do after reading that :(.

Comment: Added `core_freq=250` in `/boot/config.txt` still the same result after reboot.

Comment: Take away point is that by default `ttyAMA0` is occupied by the bluetooth,  and `serial0` corresponds to a potentially less reliably timed "mini UART" -- but you can swap them back with a device tree overlay in `config.txt`.  Minicom seems to be "fussier" than other serial interaces such as `screen`; I'm not sure if I ever got it to work with an ESP8266.  The thing with which I've had the most success is `miniterm.py`, which I think you will get if you `apt install python-serial`.

Comment: Hey mate, it is working by putting these in `/boot/config.txt`, `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` and `enable_uart=1`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is working by putting `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` and `enable_uart=1` in `/boot/config.txt`.